# How to mix auto with brace-initialization to return a std::pair properly?

Tags: c++11, std-pair, stdinitializerlist

I have this example which is a function that returns a `std::pair` which holds a string value and its size.

```
std::pair<std::string, int> getLastPair(const vector<string>& vec) {
    return{ vec.back(), vec.back().size() };
}

int main(){

    vector<string> names{ "An", "Apple", "A", "Day", "Keeps", "The", 
    "Doctor", "Away"};

    auto p{getLastPair(names)}; // ok p is a pair<string, int>
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(p).name() << std::endl;

    auto p2 = { getLastPair(names) }; // why it is not a pair but an initializer list?
    std::cout << typeid(p2).name() << std::endl; // initializer list


    std::pair<std::string, int> p3 = { getLastPair(names) }; // ok a pair
    std::cout << p3.first << " : " << p3.second << std::endl;

    decltype (getLastPair(names)) p4 = { getLastPair(names) }; // ok
    std::cout << p4.first << " : " << p4.second << std::endl; // ok


}
```

- Why the first initialization returns a `pair` as expected but the second one `p2` is not a `pair` but an `initializer_list` instead?
- As you can see `p3` works fine (returns a pair) aslong as I've provided the type explicitly!?
- Is the problem in Type Specifier `auto`?
- Also `p4` works fine with `decltype`.

Comment: Why are you using curly braces like this at all?  The curly braces on `p` make sense, but the ones on `p2`, `p3` and `p4` don't, so just get rid of them and use normal assignments: `auto p2 = getLastPair(names); ... std::pair<std::string, int> p3 = getLastPair(names); decltype (getLastPair(names)) p4 = getLastPair(names);`

Comment: For `p2`, you have `auto` on the left and a one-element initializer list on the right. Why is it surprising that `auto` is deduced to be an `initializer_list`?